# RESTful Dictionary Service?

Tags: web-services, bash, rest, shell

this is only loosely programming related.
I wrote myself a shellscript, that extracts all acronyms from a text and writes them to a file. Now I would like to process that file to add the definitions.

My first google [hit](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/10/dictionary-lookup-via-command-line.html) suggested using curl and the `dict://` url scheme. However I am behind a proxy, which does not seem to allow that.

Does any of you know a service that is similar to the `dict://` but is provided via HTTP?
Ideally it would be restful since messing around with SOAP seems somewhat bloated for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of Dictionary API services listed on http://www.programmableweb.com

Comment: Thanks :-) Very valuable source.